How can I estimate the time and cost (in relation to the machine and vocabulary) to enumerate sentences of English of n words?
I want to consider:

a vocabulary $V$ of $n$ distinct English words
a sequence of $m$ words, selected from $V$ (with repetition allowed)
a function $a$ which enumerates all unique sequences of $m$ words from $V$
a function $f$ which approximates the time taken to execute function $a$ on a specific machine $m$
a function $g$ which estimates “operating costs” for executing function $a$ on machine $m$

I would then like to enumerate values for $f$ and $g$ for natural number values of $m$ and $n$.
The expression specifying the set of sentences of length $m$ - $a(m, V_n)$ - is “the Cartesian $m$-product of $V$ with itself”. This is known to have size $|V|^m = n^m$. Then the size of the set of sentences of length up to $m$ is the union of the set of $a(m, V_n)$ indexed by the ordinal set $m = \{0, 1, …, m - 1\}$. Unions of sets commutes with addition on ordinal numbers under the cardinality function $|\circ|$. Then the number of sentences up to $m$ is $\sum_{k = 0}^{m - 1}a(k, V_n)$. (I think I made a mistake here but ah well.)
What I do not know is how to accurately estimate the clock time taken to generate such sets, and an estimation for monetary cost. I mean, one can estimate “3 cents per $X$”, but I don’t know what $X$ should be. Clock cycles of the CPU?

If you want to do some estimation, what could be possible is counting bit operations.
On a modern computer, one can expect to do roughly $10^9$ bit operations per second (depending on the processor, and on the programming language used, but again, this is an estimation).
Dedicated servers can be rented for roughly $\\\$100$/month, that means $\\\$0.0000386$/second, so $\\\$3.86\times 10^{-14}$/operation.
Of course, those computations would only give orders of magnitude, but I am not sure anything more precise could be done.
